# How to filter rows with a column describing ranges in string in SQL

Tags: mysql

Assuming there are two tables follows:

table 1

```
| type     | ranges |
| -------- | -------------- |
| type1    | 123,100-200|
| type2    | 250-500|
```

The ranges can be either continuous or discret values.

table 2

```
| id       | value |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 260|
| 2        | 123|
```

How to write the select SQL to find type of each id belongs to?

```
select id,type 
from table2 
    left join table1 on IS_VALUE_WITHIN_RANGE(table2.value,table1.ranges)
```

result:

```
| id | type|
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | type2|
| 2        | type1|
```

For example, id=1,value=260 is between 250-500 which should belong to type2, and value 123 matches type1.

Comment: You should read this article and redesign your database. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/database-normalization-in-sql-with-examples

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff Thanks for the article <3 .

Comment: Yeah, redesigning your data structure is a more viable option. Working with your current data structure requires you to write a function that parses the content of the ranges field, identifies each comma separated range, determines if the range is a single value or a range, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Step1: Remove all `,`
- Step2: Split range by `-`, to get start and end range
- Step3: Convert range to the integer type
- step4: Perform the join with `between` to get the required output

```
with range_split as (

select
*,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(ranges,',',""),'\\d+') as range_start,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE(ranges,',',""),'\\d+$') as range_end

from [table1]
),

to_integer_type as (

select 
*,
cast(range_start as UNSIGNED) as range_start_int,
cast(range_end as UNSIGNED)  as range_end_int
from range_split
)

select 
table2.id,
to_integer_type.type
from table2
left join to_integer_type
on table2.value between to_integer_type.range_start_int and to_integer_type.range_end_int
```